# Move nested value in jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a json like this:

```
{
  "key_1": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "foo"
  },
  "key_2": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "bar"
  }
}
```

that I would like to output like this

```
{
  "key_1": "foo",
  "key_2": "bar"
}
```

`jq '.[].value'` will give me the values:

```
"foo"
"bar"
```

while this `jq '(.[] = .[].value)'` will give me

```
{
  "key_1": "foo",
  "key_2": "foo"
}
{
  "key_1": "bar",
  "key_2": "bar"
}
```

So I'm not sure..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the task entails mapping the values of the top-level keys, `map_values` should come to mind:

```
map_values(.value)
```

You could also use `with_entries`, which might make sense if you wanted to manipulate the top-level keys as well:

```
with_entries( .value |= .value )
```

Comment: This gives me an array with the values, but how can I reconstruct the key-value object?

Comment: did you run it?  this produces the key: value object you requested!

Comment: I did and I'm not sure what I wrote! I tried again and it worked like a charm! Thanks!